# Twitter Bootstrap 3 multi column ul list sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For multi column lists I read [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists). But I want to know is there a Bootstrap way. Because I read that some browsers doesn't support multi columns. So if bootstrap has a way it would be more error-prone.

I have an ul list like this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/UrGJT/

```
< div class="sidebar_wrapper">  
    < div class="sidebar_inner">  
        < ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">  
            < li>My super link</li>  
            < li>My super link</li>  
            < li>My super link</li>  
            < li>My super link</li>  
            ......  
        < /ul>  
    < /div >   
< /div >
```

I want this behaviour:

- If user's monitor has adequate height, all 18 rows will be visible.
- If user has smaller screen, for example there will be two columns, 9 in each column. (I don't want to scrollbar to appear)
- If user has very small screen like mobile phone, a scrollbar will appear so he/she can find what he needs.
- It would be better to minimize line heights for small devices.
- I'm open to any recommendation to increase responsivity.

Comment: for desktop you use 100% divide by 18, for smaller screen use 100% divide by 9, and so on...All with inline block

Comment: I sort of understand what you're trying to do, but it almost seems like you're doing it the wrong way round. Usually the smaller the screen, the less columns you get. A very small screen (such as a mobile) with 4 columns would be impossible to see the content.

Comment: @Coop what would you recommend for mobile phones ? I edited question. After your comment, I think a mobile phone user will prefer a sidebar with scrollbar.

Comment: What about doing it the other way round? More columns on larger screens? Either way, I guess in answer to your question, yes it is possible with Bootstrap. The newest version allows you to change column layouts specific to the screen size. It's pretty cool.

Comment: I use "col-md" classes extensively. But I need a wrapping behaviour. Else I should write 3-4 sidebars for each device (xs,sm,md,lg)

Comment: If you code it up for the largest amount of columns first and use <ul> as a wrapper for each row. You'd have multiple lists but it wouldn't look any different.

Comment: I'm surely out of subject, but here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A7MYE/4/), it's a flexible and responsive design